# Having issues with .bind

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
for( var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
   if(array[i] instanceof Buff) {
   someDiv[i].onclick = buffTest.bind(i);
   }
}
```

I'm really tempted to just do something like `someDiv[i].onclick = function() { buffTest(i) };` but for the sake of actually learning what's wrong and improving, I would like to understand what I'm doing wrong. Am I using bind wrong in some way? I forgot to mention, the issue I'm having is:

```
function buffTest(yy){
console.log(yy);
}
```

console.log returns a MouseEvent instead of the number from i. any help on the matter is GREATLY appreciated, thanks in advance for any info.

Comment: It's an object, sorry for not making it more understandable. Not sure if it's called an object exactly but it's when you do `function Buff(val1, val2, val3) { this.a = val1; this.b = val2 etc }` and `var someVar = new Buff( 1 2 3 );`

Comment: The first parameter of `bind` is the context, as in `call` and `apply`.

Comment: @HateNames That's indeed an object.

Comment: How, would `array[i]` ever be an instance of `Buff`, unless you have an array of `new Buff()`s? Also, why would you `bind` an array increment to `buffTest`? You have no `this` keyword in `buffTest`.

Comment: @elclanrs Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. I went with using .bind so that it doesn't call the function on the spot when I set it. PHPglue Easy, array[0] = new Test(), array[1] = new Different(), array[2] = new Buff(). In my example I only need the Buff objects to do a specific something. Also thanks Boaz for giving me a direct answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably just because the first argument of [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is the `this` value.

You probably want this instead:

```
someDiv[i].onclick = buffTest.bind(someDiv[i], i);
```

EDIT: Like @bfavarette stated, if you do not mind what `this` will be in your listener, you could also pass `null` instead of `someDiv[i]`, but since when attaching event listeners using this method, you expect `this` to be the object on which the listener was attached, I sticked to that behavior in the sample I provided.

Comment: Or even `buffTest.bind(null, i)`

Comment: @bfavaretto, Well i guess it would depend if he's using `this` inside his function. Normally when you attach listeners using this method, you expect the value of `this` to be the object on which the listener was attached.

Comment: Dang, it was that simple. I didn't know the first value would go to this, or at least I didnt think it would give the first var in buffTest( var1 ) to this. Sorry for missing that and making a pointless question

Answer (score 2):

`bind` does two jobs: it sets the `this` value for the function when it gets called later, and it pre-fills function arguments. If you just want to set the `this` value, you pass it as the first argument. Any arguments after the first are used to "pre-fill" the function parameters.

In your case, you just want to pre-fill parameters, so set the first parameter of `bind` to `null` or `window` or anything else. `i` should be the second parameter.

```
buffTest.bind(
  null, // doesn't matter
  i     // pre-fills the first argument to buffTest
)
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining it, can't believe I missed something so simple. Thanks for taking the time to answer and sorry for the boring question, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function makeTest(i) {
    return function () {
        buffTest(i);
    };
}

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] instanceof Buff) {
        someDiv[i].onclick = makeTest(i);
    }
}
```